# cannot get decorator pattern to work

Tags: java, design-patterns

Please see code below. I cannot see where I am going wrong. I am also very confused! Much obliged for any help!

```
package code;

public class Client {

 public static void main(String[] args){

     proxyPlane plane = new proxyPlane(new Pilot(18));
        plane.flyPlane();

        plane = new proxyPlane(new Pilot(25));
        plane.flyPlane();

        DecoratedPilot decPilot = new Pilot(35);

        System.out.println("Experienced Pilot of age " + Pilot.Age() + " " + decPilot.getDecotation());   
    }

}


package code;

public interface DecoratedPilot {

public String getDecotation();
}


package code;

public class Decoration extends PilotDecorator {

public Decoration(Pilot pilot) {
    super(pilot);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String getDecotation() {
    return "Pilot has earned his Commercial Wings";
}
}


package code;

public abstract class PilotDecorator implements DecoratedPilot {

public PilotDecorator(Pilot pilot)
{
    apilot = pilot;
}
}


package code;

public class Pilot implements DecoratedPilot {

private static int age;

public static int Age() {

    return age;  
}

public Pilot(int age){

    Pilot.age = age;
}

public String getDecotation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: What output do you get, and what output do you expect?

Comment: Please indent and format the code correctly, its really hard to read like this.

Comment: thanks for the reformatting, I am still new to the forum - the output I get is from the Pilot class and it needs to come from Decoration class. Plus Pilot class keeps asking for the getDecotation() method when I remove it. Tutorials are not getting me anywhere....

Comment: @AljoshaBre - that could me mumbo jumbo from earlier attempts, my apologies, I need Client to get the string "Pilot has earned..." from decorator without adding anything to Pilot class.....in fact I need to remove "public String getDecotation()" from it...

Comment: This is not the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). First, try to write the example in the link, learn how it works and then implement your own solution

Answer (score 3):

Here :

---

```
        package code;

        public class Client {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // -- A standard pilot
                Pilot standardPilot = new StandardPilot(35);
                System.out.println("Pilot : " + standardPilot.getAge() + " - " + standardPilot.getDescription());
                // -- A decorated pilot
                Pilot decoratedPilot = new DecoratedPilot(standardPilot);
                System.out.println("Pilot : " + decoratedPilot.getAge() + " - " + decoratedPilot.getDescription());
            }
        }
```

---

```
        package code;

        public interface Pilot {
            int getAge();
            String getDescription();
        }
```

---

```
    package code;

    public class StandardPilot implements Pilot {

        private int age;

        public StandardPilot(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Standard Pilot";
        }
```

}

---

```
package code;

public class DecoratedPilot implements Pilot {

    private Pilot pilot;

    public DecoratedPilot(Pilot pilot) {
        // todo : check not null
        this.pilot = pilot;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return pilot.getAge();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Decorated Pilot";
    }
}
```

If you need several decorators, you can make `DecoratedPilot` abstract and inherits each specific decorator from it.

Comment: Its important to note that the decorated method here is getAge(). Typically, for the decorated method, the Decorator would do its part and then call the decorated method on the containing (inner or wrapped) object.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not actually decorating anything. That is, you're not "wrapping" a Component with a Decorator.

Here's an example of the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

An excellent example of this pattern is in the book: [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124). I really like this book and highly recommend it if you dont already have it.

Comment: how do I get one class to wrap another..?

Comment: @user1360809, By passing in an object to the constructor, like yanflea did in his answer. Like this: Pilot decoratedPilot = new DecoratedPilot(standardPilot);